# Eigenvectors, generalized eigenvectors and stability

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, symplectic-geometry, stability-theory

I'm currently studying the stability conditions for symplectic matrices, but I've some doubts that probably stem directly from basic linear algebra.

Let $M$ be a 4x4 real symplectic matrix.

Let $V$ be its eigenvector, with $e^{i\theta}$ as eigenvalue ($\theta \in \mathbb R$), **i.e.** $MV = e^{i \theta}V$.
It is possibile to prove that in this case we have that $e^{-i \theta}$ is another eigenvalue with eigenvector $V^*$, **i.e.** $MV^* = e^{-i \theta}V^*$ (where the superscript $^*$ stands for "complex conjugate").

Suppose there is too a generalized eigenvector $W$, **i.e.** $MW = e^{i \theta}W + V$.

- Does it mean that there's too a complex conjugate generalized eigenvector $W^*$, **i.e.** $MW^* = e^{-i \theta}W^* + V^*$?
- How many invariant bidimensional subspaces does the matrix $M$ have?
- Depending on the eigenvalues ($e^{\pm i \theta} = \pm 1$ or $e^{\pm i \theta} \neq \pm 1$), is there a difference in the number of those invariant subspaces?

Comment: Just start with the defining equation for an eigenvalue, eigenvector or generalized eigenvector and take the conjugate on both sides.

Comment: Thanks @P.Lawrence, I suppose the answer to my first question is "yes". Do you have any insight also for the other two?